# Act/Identity of Hurtling in "A runway car came hurtling towards us""

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, parts-of-speech

> **A runway car came hurtling towards us.**

Here *hurtling* is a ________?

Comment: What did your research for the word "hurtling" tell you?

Answer (score 0):

***Hurtling*** is a descriptive gerund in that sentence.

Comment: I know gerunds act as nouns. But here 'Came' is a intransitive verb after which an object [noun/gerund] is not nessary. I mean, after intransitive verb, adver or prepositiinal phrase( may be other things also) can be used, but not gerund.

Comment: After linking verb, descriptive gerund can be used like ' Work is earning/My job is earning money. Here came is not a linking verb,is it?

Comment: Descriptive gerunds can be used with verbs, directly after them. I'm not sure I can articulate a rule for when they can, but it means to be doing that action *at the same time*. For example, "he died **laughing**" means he was laughing at the time he died.